# Pasar datos de un JTable a otro JTable

Tags: java, jframe, combobox, jtable, jtextfield

en mi JFrame tengo 2 JTable, 1 JTextField, 1 ComboBox y 1 JButton.
Necesito que primero se seleccione una fila del primer JTable, se llene el JTextField y se seleccione un objeto del comboBox, y al presionar el botón todos estos datos pasen al segundo JTable, el problema es que no sé cómo seleccionar los datos de la fila seleccionada del primer JTable para colocarlos en el segundo. Si alguien me pudiese ayudar con esa parte estaría agradecida.

```
public class FrmPedido extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private DefaultTableModel modelo;
public static RegistroProductos lista;
int con = 0;
private int seleccionFila;

//Constructor de JFrame
public FrmPedido(RegistroProductos lista) {
    initComponents();
    CargarInterfaz();
    Producto producto;
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.getRegistros(); i++) {
        producto = (Producto)lista.getRegistroProducto(i);
        MostrarDatos(producto);
    }
}

//Método para llenar la tabla
public void MostrarDatos(Producto producto){
    modelo.insertRow(con, new Object[]{});
    modelo.setValueAt(producto.getNombre(), con, 0);
    modelo.setValueAt(producto.getPrecio(), con, 1);
    con++;
}

//Método para crer la tabla
public void CargarInterfaz(){
    String data[][] = {};
    String col[] = {"Nombre", "Precio"};
    modelo = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
    tblProducto.setModel(modelo);
}
private void tblProductoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    seleccionFila= tblProducto.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
}                                        

private void btnAgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        String nombre = String.valueOf(tblProducto.getValueAt(seleccionFila, 0));
        double precio = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(tblProducto.getValueAt(seleccionFila, 1)));
        int distancia = Integer.parseInt(txtDistancia.getText());
        String vehiculo = cboVehiculo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int index = cboVehiculo.getSelectedIndex();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
    }
}
```

Ya tengo los datos llenados de la primera tabla que toma de un arraylist, pero para llenar la segunda tabla no se si debo volver a crear un nuevo Modelo para ello. El otro JTable tiene de nombre tblPedido

Comment: Buenas, Crystal, bienvenida al sitio. [Esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10130736/2553194) te indica donde puedes conseguir un ejemplo de lo que buscas. Si tienes algún problema, vuelve por aquí, pero no te olvides de incluir un ejemplo mínimo verificable de lo que hayas hecho

Comment: Mi error, ya coloqué lo que creo es el código fundamental del JFrame

Comment: No te preocupes, ha mejorado, pero con lo que has puesto, todavía no puede copiarse y ejecutarse, faltan aún algunas piezas. Respondiendo a parte de tu pregunta, sí, necesitas dos modelos, uno por tabla.